# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in error log

Tags: wordpress

I got this error in my **error log**

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    if ( $field['name'] == $fieldname ) {
        $characteristics = $field;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. The site is not an alternative to debugging your code yourself.. Before posting a question, it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to fix the issue yourself.  Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

one problem is if your variable is empty and inside a `foreach` loop the warning appears

Try this

```
if (is_array($fields) || is_object($fields)) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if ($field['name'] == $fieldname) {
           $characteristics = $field;
        }
    }
}
```